# Nested statements in Laravel blade templating

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have the following statement(s) in my PHP and I need to make them `bladey`:

```
<?php

    if($project->nodes()->count()) {

        foreach($project->nodes()->get() as $node) {

            if($node->nodeable instanceof \App\Image) {

                // do something

            } else {

                // do something else

            }

        }

    }

?>
```

Is there a way to make it more `blade-friendly`? Or sometimes I just have to switch back to old school PHP templating like so? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the default php control structure syntax with blade syntax and save it with `.blade.php` extension.

View [Blade syntax for control strctures](http://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#control-structures) for more on this

```
@if($project->nodes()->count())

    @foreach($project->nodes()->get() as $node)

        @if($node->nodeable instanceof \App\Image)

            // do something

        @else

            // do something else

        @endif

    @endforeach

@endif
```

Comment: yeah that's what I ended up with. I was thinking maybe there was a different way to write it. But thanks!